# ResultSet: Exception: set type is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY -- why?

Tags: java, sql, resultset, jdbc-odbc

I have very simple code:

```
pstat=con.prepareStatement("select typeid from users where username=? and password=?");             
pstat.setString(1, username);
pstat.setString(2, password);
rs=pstat.executeQuery();
int rowCount=0;
while(rs.next())
{       
    rowCount++;         
}
rs.beforeFirst();
if(rowCount>=1)
{
while(rs.next())
{
    typeID=rs.getInt(1);
}
```

But when execute this code I am getting...

```
java.sql.SQLException: Result set type is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.beforeFirst(Unknown Source)
at server.ClientImpl.login(ClientImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: This question NEVERets old! Some how I never get this error on the platform independent J-Connector 8.0.15! So give this fluke a try ;-)

Answer (score 35):

Change your first statement to this

```
pstat=con.prepareStatement("select typeid from users where username=? and password=?",
                            ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, 
                        ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

This way you can move forward and backward, so less things to worry about

Comment: Just a quick note, make sure your JDBC driver supports these types. SQLite for example doesn't - in this case, if you need to move backwards, consider using another JDBC driver.

Answer (score 21):

The type **TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY** means you can only move forward on the result set, not backward, so you get an exception when you try to go back with `beforeFirst()`. Instead you can either use the following [prepareStatement()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29), which receives the resultset type as a parameter, or to do:

```
        pstat=con.prepareStatement("select typeid from users where username=? and password=?");             
        pstat.setString(1, username);
        pstat.setString(2, password);
        rs=pstat.executeQuery();
        int rowCount=0;

        while(rs.next())
        {
            rowCount++;
            typeID=rs.getInt(1);
        }
```

Comment: I was about to type that. Nice job, @MByD

Answer (score 18):

**Though this question is old, answers do not age, encountered a similar problem today, this is how I approached it, as [here](http://www.databaseskill.com/2452676/)**
This is the functionality provided by Java JDBC driver, and PostgreSQL database.
This case create a Statement object using the default parameters, the system-generated data sets can only be a one-way move the pointer forward, and not two-way mobile data record pointer, the former

Statement stmt = dbConn.createStatement (); 
Result rs = stmt.executeQuery (sql);
***Changed to*** 
Statement stmt = dbConn.createStatement (ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
Result rs = stmt.executeQuery (sql); 
Generated at this time rs can use rs.first () reverse move the pointer operation

Answer (score 11):

You can only do this with a resultset that is of type TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, which is defined as "The constant indicating the type for a ResultSet object that is scrollable and generally sensitive to changes made by others."

You need to do something like the following ...

```
Statement statement = 
 connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

Answer (score 6):

java.sql.SQLException: Result set type is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY

with JDBC 2.0 API, the user has the flexibility to move the cursor either forward or backward.

Your error can be removed by creating the statemnt as follows

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

Also, a better way to count the number of rows would be

```
rs=pstat.executeQuery();                //execute the query
rs.last();                              //move the cursor to the last row
int numberOfRows = rs.getRow();         //get the number of rows
rs.beforeFirst();                       //back to initial state
```

Answer (score 3):

Like the exception says: You can't scroll your result set in any other direction than forwards. So when you loop through your result set to get the row count (I don't even understand why you do it), then this row will throw that exception:

```
rs.beforeFirst();
```

because that would scroll backwards.

Either create your statement so that you can scroll it (Google for examples) or remove that row counting. I'd suggest the latter, since the count seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

This question is pretty old. I believe the solution would already have been found. However, i would like to suggest here something different from what Aditya did.

```
pstat=con.prepareStatement("select typeid from users where username=? and password=?",
                                ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, 
                            ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

Instead of ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, i would use INSENSITIVE

[Check this link for refernce](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

Answer (score 1):

the rowCount variable is not necessary . you are performing two loops on the rs . only the second loop is necessary to get the number of rows which is done by this part of code:

```
 while (rs.next()){
 typeID=rs.getInt(1); //typeID is the number of rows in the ResultSet
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Java 8 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) states the following:

> A default ResultSet object is not updatable and has a cursor that moves forward only. Thus, you can iterate through it only once and only from the first row to the last row. It is possible to produce ResultSet objects that are scrollable and/or updatable. The following code fragment, in which con is a valid Connection object, illustrates how to make a result set that is scrollable and insensitive to updates by others, and that is updatable. See ResultSet fields for other options.

```
   Statement stmt = con.createStatement(
                                  ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                                  ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
   ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b FROM TABLE2");
   // rs will be scrollable, will not show changes made by others,
   // and will be updatable
```