# how to make previous button for show data in java?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I tried to make **previous button** to *show data from database* by sql library (java.sql.* ), so I have this exception `java.sql.SQLException : ResultSet is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`.

I done it by this code:

```
       private void b_previousActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        int i = this.page;
        while(i == this.page){
            try{
                if(conn.rs.previous()){
            conn.rs.previous();
            this.page = conn.rs.getInt("page");
            this.contact = conn.rs.getString("contact");
            show_quran.setText(this.contact);}
                else{
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + " : " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Take a look here [resultset-exception-set-type-is-type-forward-only-why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367737/resultset-exception-set-type-is-type-forward-only-why)

Comment: cherck the javadoc for [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) to see how you can configure the cursor.

Comment: Post the code of statement and connection creation.

Comment: This is the code for connection:
    
public void db_connect(){
        try{
          Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:quran.db");
          stmt = conn.createStatement();
          System.out.println("^_^");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + " : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    

and this for stmt:
    
conn.stmt = conn.conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

Answer (score 2):

Because by default backward seeking is disabled in java. So to go previous you have to enable `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE` 
Detailed description of ResultSet types can be found [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html#rs_interface)

Try like this as example

```
Statement s = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("your query here");
```

Then you can go for backward seek.

Comment: Thanks @Maximin , I tried what you said, than I have now this exception:   `java.sql.SQLException : SQLite only supports TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY cursors`

Comment: @Abdullah Because SQLite doesn't support backward seek.